# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Firestore$1', but it was: a custom Firestore object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run local testing for my firebase project, I'm using the admin SDK and trying to connect to the Firestore emulator. I believe that this is where the code that is failing but I'm not sure how to check that (I am quite new).

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = "localhost:8080";

const db = admin.firestore();
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are not running two versions of firebase side by side.

For example, if you have a monorepo, make sure all your modules / apps have the exact same version of firebase.

Firebase will give you that error if you are trying to run your tests with a firebase client that does not match your server's firebase version.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error from an auto-import when trying to use the Lite Firestore SDK

```
import { connectFirestoreEmulator  } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
```

but imported from vanilla firestore

```
import { connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase/firestore';
```